# Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables 11

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

My code against SQL injection isn't working (error message in title).

I simplified my code, but its still not working.

```
<?php
include "conf.php";

$db = new mysqli($MYSQL_HOST, $MYSQL_USER, $MYSQL_PASS, $MYSQL_DB);

$ltime =10;
$url= 1;
$title =2;



$result = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO links VALUES ('', ?, ?, ?)");
$result->bind_param('ss', $url, $title, $ltime);
$result->execute();
```

I created DB and all variables are integer, first value is ID and it is created with an auto Increment flag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to put three "s" in the bind_param method, because there are three variables to bind

```
$result = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO links VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?)");

$result->bind_param('sss', $url, $title, $ltime);
```

I's also better to pass a null NULL value for the autoincremented field instead of an empty string

Answer (score 2):

You have:

```
$result->bind_param('ss', $url, $title, $ltime);
```

but it should be

```
$result->bind_param('sss', $url, $title, $ltime);
```

The first function parameter of
[`bool mysqli_stmt::bind_param ( string $types , mixed &$var1 [, mixed &$... ] )`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)
determines the type of *each single* bound variable/sql-parameter. You have three sql-parameters, so your first function parameter must specify three types (three times `s` in this case), not just two.

And on a side-node: I'd rather assign the return value of mysqli::prepare to a variable with the name `$statement` than `$result`.